# What are the solutions for com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl.Sort issue?

Tags: spring-boot, sdk, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

This is one of error getting class,

```
import com.bookingsite.acme.config.document.paymentoption.PaymentGatewayConfiguration;
import com.bookingsite.acme.config.dto.paymentgatewaysearchrequest.PaymentGatewayConfigSearchRequestDTO;
import com.bookingsite.acme.config.dto.paymentgatewaysearchrequest.PaymentOptionsDTO;
import com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl.Sort;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
public class PaymentGatewaySearchData {

    private String searchQuery;
    private Sort sort;
    private int offset;
    private int limit;
    private int totalCount;

    private List<PaymentGatewayConfiguration> paymentGatewaySearchResponseList;

    private PaymentGatewayConfigSearchRequestDTO paymentGatewayConfigSearchRequestDTO;

    private List<PaymentOptionsDTO> paymentOptions;

}
```

I Upgraded Spring boot version to 2.7.4 and currently we using Couchbase to SDK3 version.After that getting this error.

other used methords

```
public Sort getOrderByQuery(
            PaymentTemplateConfigSearchFilterRequestDTO paymentTemplateConfigSearchFilterRequestDTO) {

        if (validateOrderBy(paymentTemplateConfigSearchFilterRequestDTO)) {
            if (paymentTemplateConfigSearchFilterRequestDTO.getSortDirection().equals(SortDirectionDTO.DESCENDING)) {
                return Sort.desc(paymentTemplateConfigSearchFilterRequestDTO.getSortBy().getAction());
            } else {
                return Sort.asc(paymentTemplateConfigSearchFilterRequestDTO.getSortBy().getAction());
            }

        } else {

            return Sort.desc(N1QlQueryConstants.TEMPLATEMODIFIEDDATE);

        }

    }
```

**What would be the best possible options?**

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine the compiler is complaining that `com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl.Sort` does not exist.

[This Couchbase Forum post](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/dsl-support-deprecated-in-3-x-what-is-alternative/30848) explains why the classes in `com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl` from SDK 2 were not carried forward to SDK 3.

If you wish to continue using the DSL classes, the recommendation is to copy [the relevant source code from SDK 2](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client/tree/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/java/query/dsl) into your project.

UPDATE: There's now a GitHub repo with the "missing" experimental Query DSL classes from SDK 2, adapted for SDK 3. Now it really should be as simple as copying these classes into your project: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-java-sdk2-migration-kit

Comment: Thank you very much for reply.This will helpful a lot.Can you explain where should I integrate the specified couchbase dsl changes to should it be integrated in to my code base?Could you please explain.Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Step 1: Clone the [SDK 2 repository](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client). Step 2: Create package `com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl.` in your own project. Step 3: Find that package in the SDK 2 source code, and copy all of the files to the corresponding location in your project. Step 4: Compile your project, and and fix any compilation issues you discover.

Comment: If your company has an enterprise subscription license and you need additional help, consider reaching out to Couchbase Technical Support or Professional Services.

Comment: Where can I find these dependencies used in many of the DSL folders? I cannot find these files in the Git repository provided about

import com.couchbase.client.core.annotations.InterfaceAudience;
import com.couchbase.client.core.annotations.InterfaceStability;

These files are found in the Couchbase JVM core repository. How can we use it in the above scenario? Is it not available in Couchbase sdk3?

https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-jvm-core/tree/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/client/core/annotations

Comment: These imports are also used in the DSL package. But could not locate them in the repositories.

import com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.internal.StringUtil;
import com.couchbase.client.deps.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonStringEncoder;

Comment: You can remove all references to those annotations. They're just for documenting whether something is part of the SDK's public API.

Comment: For `StringUtil.isNullOrEmpty`, you can replace it with this: `public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s) { return s == null || s.isEmpty(); }`

Comment: For `JsonStringEncoder`, remove the `com.couchbase.client.deps.` prefix from the package name, and add Jackson to your project: https://central.sonatype.dev/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.13.4

Comment: dnault your com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl. fixing steps are worked properly. Now I faced an issue with project test case coverage. Do you have any idea to fix it? Can we have import com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl. with Gradle dependencies or convert it to lib or jar?

Comment: @gimhanas There are no plans to publish the DSL classes as a JAR. You could exclude the package from your test coverage results, or add the test cases from the [couchbase-java-sdk2-migration-kit](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-java-sdk2-migration-kit) GitHub repo to your project.

Answer (score 0):

QueryDSL is back in spring-data-couchbase.

Can you please open an issue for this?
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues

Comment: The user is looking for a couchbase implementation of querydsl.  I pointed to one.

Comment: "then why do you ask for creating an issue?"

In case they care to provide more information than "After that getting this error."  There are three of of us from couchbase (Matthew Groves,  dnault and myself) trying to help this user. And all we have to go on is "After getting this error".

Comment: "If you do not contribute anything but a link, then this is a link-only answer"

Oh please. I told them that QueryDSL is in spring-data-couchbase (which they are apparently already using based on the code they provided).  

If you don't understand what QueryDSL is, or the significance of it being in spring-data-couchbase when that was what the user was looking for I cannot help you.

I might know a thing or two about QueryDSL in spring-data-couchbase. I wrote it.  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase/issues/1288

Comment: If "QueryDSL is back in spring-data-couchbase." is what you consider your contributed solution, then OK. I propose to focus the answer post on that and use a comment to ask OP to create an issue or to provide sufficient debugging info here. You (I assume one of your team has sufficient reputation) can also close vote the question for lack of debugging details.

Comment: That is the right way to tell a question author that the question does not contain enough information for helping them. The fact that the question gets closed if some people agree with you and then no additional answers are possible puts a little strength into that. The question author is then motivated to rework the question and add the needed details. This is different from "threaten to have their post removed". It is only removed if it gets closed and then downvoted and then delete-voted. Which  usually does not happen if OP does indeed add info.

Comment: Is it not possible to provide a solution for the presumed problem AND solicit further information?

Comment: It is. Provide the solution in an answer post and ask for the ticket or more info in a comment. If you think that the question is not answerable without the info you are asking for, then vote to close it.