# How to resolve getCouchbaseOperations() related dependencies using Spring Data Couchbase (version 4.4.5)

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Spring Data Couchbase documentation (version 4.4.5) specifies that the method **getCouchbaseOperations()** has also been removed. It also states that you still can access all methods from the **native Java SDK via the class CouchbaseTemplate or Cluster**. But I couldn't resolve this. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.migrating.repository)

The code below is from Couchbase SDK 2 implementation. I opted to migrate the deprecated **DSL packages** into my code as specified in below mentioned thread. ([What are the solutions for com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl.Sort issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74124732/what-are-the-solutions-for-com-couchbase-client-java-query-dsl-sort-issue))

I am currently facing the issue of resolving getCouchbaseOperations() related issues. Could someone please specify how I may handle this as a scenario?

```
package com.acme.acmepay.config.dao;

import com.acme.acmepay.config.document.paymentoption.PaymentGatewayConfiguration;
import com.acme.acmepay.config.logic.paymenttemplatereportlogic.data.PaymentTemplateDataTableSearchLogicData;
import com.acme.acmepay.config.repository.PaymentGatewayConfigurationRepository;
import com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket;
import com.couchbase.client.java.query.N1qlQuery;
import com.couchbase.client.java.query.Statement;
import com.couchbase.client.java.query.dsl.Expression;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.support.N1qlUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class PaymentTemplateConfigDAOImpl implements PaymentTemplateConfigDAO {

    @Autowired
    PaymentGatewayConfigurationRepository paymentGatewayConfigurationRepository;

    Bucket couchbaseBucket;

    public List<PaymentGatewayConfiguration> getPaymentTemplateSearchReportList(
            PaymentTemplateDataTableSearchLogicData paymentTemplateDataTableSearchLogicData) {


        Statement statement = getQueryStatement(paymentTemplateDataTableSearchLogicData);
        log.info("N1QL Statement" + statement);

      //Error happen here
        N1qlQuery query = N1qlQuery.simple(statement);
        
        return paymentGatewayConfigurationRepository.getCouchbaseOperations().findByN1QL(query,
                PaymentGatewayConfiguration.class);


    }
    
    private Statement getQueryStatement(
            PaymentTemplateDataTableSearchLogicData paymentTemplateDataTableSearchLogicData) {

        //Error happen here
        return N1qlUtils
                .createSelectClauseForEntity(
                        paymentGatewayConfigurationRepository.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket().name())
                .from(Expression
                        .i(paymentGatewayConfigurationRepository.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket().name()))
                .where(paymentTemplateDataTableSearchLogicData.getSearchQuery())
                .orderBy(paymentTemplateDataTableSearchLogicData.getSort())
                .limit(paymentTemplateDataTableSearchLogicData.getLimit())
                .offset(paymentTemplateDataTableSearchLogicData.getOffset());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The couchbase cluster (and bucket etc) are exposed via getCouchbaseClientFactory() method on the CouchbaseTemplate.

couchbaseTemplate.getCouchbaseClientFactory().getCluster()

The api docs are here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/4.4.6/api/